# How many fleets has Anakin wiped out and lost?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, anakin-skywalker

Anakin Skywalker has, at least in the eyes of Obi-Wan and Ahsoka if not also the other Jedi leaders, earned quite a reputation for trashing his starships and fleets during the Clone Wars.

Out of all the recorded instances in the Clone Wars, how many Separatist fleets has Anakin obliterated, and how many Republic fleets has he lost in the process? For it to be counted, a maximum of one ship in the entire fleet may survive - as such, the lone ship that survived the breaking of the Ryloth blockade would count. Any circumstance that would have Obi-Wan go "what happened to your fleet yet again?" would qualify honestly.

Comment: Can you cite a single instance where he is said to be forgetful/careless about his fleets?

Comment: @valorum I read the question more so that it isnt exaclty carelessness but also bad luck that he means there. (anakin really had a talend with hgis own space fighters.....still though I dont remember more than once that he lost fleets)

Comment: @Thomas - I can't remember when it happened *even once*.

Comment: @valorum I THINK he lost his own capital ship once or twice (not sure though when). His starfighters though....he is the james bond of the jedi there and his starfighter his car :)

Comment: @Thomas - He loses lightsabers quite regularly, for sure.

Comment: He once rammed into a battle station to overcome a blockade, but I don't recall any instances in which he lost his fleet by carelessness.